# Restfb - Using the Batch Request API

Tags: java, restfb

This is my FQL. What it does is it receives the post based on post_id, and also returns if post was made by user or page. User or page is returned based on id of the one who posted the post, which is returned by first FQLQuery.

```
StringBuilder fqlQuery = new StringBuilder();
                    fqlQuery.append("SELECT "
                            + FacebookGraphApi.FQL_STREAM_SELECT
                            + " FROM stream WHERE post_id=\"");
                    fqlQuery.append(rmtId);
                    fqlQuery.append("\"");

                    HashMap<String, String> querys = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    querys.put("messages", fqlQuery.toString());
                    querys.put(
                            "users",
                            "SELECT "
                                    + FacebookGraphApi.FQL_USER_SELECT
                                    + " FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #messages)");
                    querys.put(
                            "pages",
                            "SELECT "
                                    + FacebookGraphApi.FQL_PAGE_SELECT
                                    + " FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #messages)");
```

Now what i would like to do is the same using RESTFB Batch Request API

```
BatchRequest firstRequest = new BatchRequestBuilder(rmtId)).build();
                    BatchRequest secondRequest = new BatchRequestBuilder(poster_id).build();

                    List<BatchResponse> batchResponses =
                              facebookClient.executeBatch(firstRequest,secondRequest);
```

These are 2 batches that executes, first one returns the post, and it contains "from", that contains poster_id of the one who posted, but i dont know how to put that poster_id from first batch to second batch so it would return poster information.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post the answer,

first request should contain a name method on which u depend on the other request, and search on second request that depends on first ids like this.

?ids={result=name-of-method:$.data.id}